# How to make an animation on my menu bar in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, css-transitions

**How to make my navigation bar, have a slide animation when my div button  is pressed.**

I have created the java script function for it showing up in general, but having it popping up from nowhere is kind of annoying.I want it to show and slide slowly from the top for 2-3 seconds.
I tried using the following code on the class that wraps up all (nav-list) but it didn't work out:

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.dot_a');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1 {
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2 {
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  /*border: solid black 2px;*/
}

.nav a {
  color: #747d8c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.dot_a {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

i {
  /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 32px 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
  }
  .dot_a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .dot {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .nav-list {
    display: none;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-list.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d2896764d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="dot_a">
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="nav-list">
      <a class="anchors" href="Index.html"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="HtmlPage.html"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a>
      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a> 
    </span>
  </nav>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  .nav-list{
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    
  }

  .nav-list.active {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
     opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

You have to replace this css and check.

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It messes up with my java script sir.  Also what happenes is that my anchors disappear. I don't know why or how but it just does. Thank you for trying tho<3